# php not sending messages to databses

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm sure it's a stupid mistake I've made somewhere, and I can't find the answer to this anywhere.
I'm trying to send a new insert query to my database. It successfully connects to it but for some reason it doesn't update the fields on my database. Is it a syntax error in my query? I tried everything I can think of, please help!

```
<?php 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $timestamp = time();
    $crypt = crypt($_POST['password'], $timestamp);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `dvds`.`users` (`email`, `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `timestamp`) VALUES (" . $email . ", " . $username . ", " . $first_name . ", " . $last_name . ", " . $crypt . ", " . $timestamp . ")";

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dvds");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else{
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Cheers.

Comment: Try without `$_POST` so you can focus on the database issue when troubleshooting.

Comment: Just for for thought. Next time try to `print $sql;` to see what you query actually is. This will help you debug it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments lads, appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need single quotes around the values you are inserting:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `dvds`.`users` (`email`, `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $username . "', '" . $first_name . "', '" . $last_name . "', '" . $crypt . "', '" . $timestamp . ")'";
```

You also should look into SQL injection and how to prevent, as you have a significant vulnerability there.

You may also consider using the timestamp field type in mysql rather than unix timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding string values so need to quote them as

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `dvds`.`users` 
(`email`, `username`, 
`first_name`, 
`last_name`, 
`password`, 
`timestamp`
) 
VALUES ('" . $email . "', 
'" . $username . "', 
'" . $first_name . "', 
'" . $last_name . "',
 '" . $crypt . "',
 '" . $timestamp . "'
)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are required for values:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `dvds`.`users` (`email`, `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $username . "', '" . $first_name . "', '" . $last_name . "', '" . $crypt . "', '" . $timestamp . "')";
```

Another approach without concatenating like the following below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `dvds`.`users` (`email`, `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('$email', '$username','$first_name','$last_name', '$crypt', '$timestamp')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values should be in ''(single quotation) for varachar, this was your mistake,
I am sure it will work for you

Replace

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `dvds`.`users` (`email`, `username`,
     `first_name`, `last_name`,
      `password`, `timestamp`) VALUES (" . $email . ", " . $username . ", 
     " . $first_name . ", " . $last_name . ", " . $crypt . ", " . $timestamp . ")";
```

with

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `dvds`.`users` (`email`, `username`, `first_name`, 
    `last_name`, `password`, `timestamp`)
     VALUES (" . "'".$email."'" . ", " .
    "'".$username."'" . ", " . "'".$first_name."'" . ", " . "'".$last_name."'" . ", " . "'".$crypt."'" . ", " . "'".$timestamp."'" . ")";
```

I